# iHasApp framework rejected by Apple?

Tags: ios, ios-urlsheme

My app has been approved before with iHasApp. A new update has been rejected by Apple with the following reason:
"Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs"
We found that this app scan all known URL schemes using a service called iHasApp.
How to fix that?

Comment: Stop using a framework that does something Apple prohibit.

Comment: Apple probably skimmed over this one and thought that it used Private APIs. Appeal saying that it doesnt and all APIs are documented.

Comment: No. "We found that this app scan all known URL schemes using a service called iHasApp".

Comment: The funny thing is that iHasApp doesn't scan all known apps. It only scans a limited subset hardcoded into a JSON file. It "knows" less than 10% of the apps actually in the App Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple recently began rejecting apps that use `canOpenURL:` simply to determine which apps are installed on a user's device. You'll have to remove the library in question.

Comment: Thanks for the good news bgilham :p .But this is 90 % of the main job of my app.There must be an approved Api which do the same as iHasApp.

Comment: It's not about whether or not an API exists - one already does - it's about how you use that API. And Apple has decided that using that API solely to determine which apps a user has on their phone is not something they want. You'll just have to adjust.